# Using File.Open on VS for MAC how do you provide a string to absolute path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

Porting code over from VS for Windows to VS for MAC.  Part of one function opens a file using File.Open (System.IO) with a string that, on windows at least, would provide the absolute path and file to open.  The same code (on VS for MAC seems to bolster the string to include the path to the current project dir binary.

To give an example here is what I'd 'like' to do:

```
File.Open("~/Projects/TestProg/UseThisFile.txt", FileMode.Open)
```

However, what occurs is an IO exception that indicates the following:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not find file
>   "/Users//Projects/TestProg/bin/Debug/TestProg.app/Contents/Resources/~/Projects/TestProg/UseThisFile.txt"

Just wondering what I am missing and/or whether I should even be using File.Open for this rather the NSFileManager (rather not have to rebase a bunch of code if I don't have to)?

Comment: What happens if you remove `~/`? I'd guess that's Windows only (given the generated path)

Comment: Removing ~/ will just cause it to try and look in "/Users//Projects/TestProg/bin/Debug/TestProg.app/Contents/Resources/Projects/TestProg/UseThisFile.txt", which wouldn't help as the file is in ~/Projects/.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use:

```
Environment.ContentRootPath
```

It works independently of your platform(Windows, Linux, MacOS)

For example:

```
File.Open($"{Environment.ContentRootPath}/UseThisFile.txt", FileMode.Open)
```

Comment: That seemed hopeful, but ContentRootPath doesn't appear to be a known member of Environment.  SystemDirectory does though, but that didn't help.  However, I can get around this by doing the following:
File.Open("/Users/<me>/UseThisFile.txt", FileMode.Open).  Although this is not ideal.

Comment: @Matt74 which .NET Core SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.ContentRootPath` is not available in a `Xamarin.Mac` Modern app.

You can use **`Environment.CurrentDirectory`**

#### Example:

```
var appContentResources = Environment.CurrentDirectory;    
Console.WriteLine(appContentResources);
```

#### Output:

```
/~~~/~~~/xamarin_mac.app/Contents/Resources
```

Comment: I'm wondering from where did you get the idea that the OP is developing on Xamarin.Mac

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The fact that his path is an `.app` path (`/Users//Projects/TestProg/bin/Debug/TestProg.app/....`) and he is using VS4M.